# Power Platform Security Roles Details

Tags: admin, powerapps, dynamics-365, power-platform

I would like to know the exact details and impact of the specific security roles, that can be assigned in the Power Platform. I am not able to find such documentation. Does anyone know where to find it?

Also, I am especially interested in this on called "Solution", located under "Customizations".
[image]

Comment: I afraid there’s no single doc to learn all this about lol

Comment: Its a damn shame

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no official doc mentioned about these details (Each privilege listed under customizations).

For any user who wants to run powerapps app (canvas app or model-driven app), he/she must own minimum privilege of the environment resource. You could find more details from following link:

[Minimum privilege to run an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/database-security#minimum-privileges-to-run-an-app)

BR

Kris